# Gradio: stop and restart callable as value?

Tags: python, gradio

Using Gradio, I have this element:

```py
gr.Markdown(lambda: str(datetime.now()), every=1.)
```

Is there a way to make it static (meaning, value is a constant string, and it no longer waits on queue) when I click a button?